# Extract single object from list in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, list

I am using a weather API to fetch data for a specific city, but i'm receiving the data in a list with 5 duplicates. I need to use the city name, minTemp, maxTemp, etc. within my app.

Essentially, I just need one of the 5 objects inside the `response` object, but I'm not sure how I can extract and use just one.

```
const apiCall = await fetch(
      `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=London&appid=${weatherAPIKey}`
    );
    const response = await apiCall.json();

  this.setState({
      city: response.list.name,
      country: response.list.sys.country,
    });
```

Will appreciate any help!

[API response object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMNgy.jpg)

Comment: Please no [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). If I want to test that code, I have to retype the whole object in, and with the formatting and hidden fields, I'd probably mess it up. If I were to write an answer, it'd probably be useless for you. Where are you stuck and what exact output are you expecting for this input? If the API call is successful, remove it from the question and just show the JSON and your attempt so far as a [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: `const [response] = await apiCall.json()` - the first element of the array (with index 0)  will be placed in the `response`

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that all 5 objects is the same, then just access the first one (or any one)

```
const response = await apiCall.json();
const firstCity = response.list[0]
const { name, country } = firstCity

this.setState({
      city: name,
      country,
    });
```